# on submit not working after loading a external form using jquery load()

Tags: jquery

I have an issue:

jQuery `.submit()` not working when I load an external form on a current page.
See the code below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="right-section job-desc col-md-12">
    <img id="cover_letter_edit" alt="" src="http://localhost/cv3/frontend_assets/images/icons/edit.png" class="float-right edit-icon">
    <h3>Cover Letter & Resume</h3>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="cover_letter_view_sec">
        <p>What is the job about? Enter overall description of your job.What is the job about? Enter overall description of
            your job.What is the job about? Enter overall description of your job.What is the job about? Enter overall description
            of your job.What is the job about? Enter overall description of your job.What is the job about? Enter overall
            description of your job.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="load_edit_cover"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //alert(2)
    $("#cover_letter_edit").click(function () {
        $("#cover_letter_view_sec").hide();
        $("#load_edit_cover").load(getBaseURL() + '/home/editCoverLetter')
    })
    $("#cover_letter_edit_sec").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(1)
    })
})
```

Loaded form content:

```
$attribute = array("id" => "cover_letter_edit_sec", "class" => "form-horizontal", "method" => "post");
echo form_open('', $attribute) ?>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3">Cover Letter</label>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="" value="" id="" class="form-control col-md-8"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3">Upload Resume</label>
    <input type="file" name="resume" value="" id="" class="form-control col-md-8">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3"></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning cancleButton">Cancle</button>
</div>
```

When i submit the form then this code is not working:

```
$("#cover_letter_edit_sec").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(1)
})
```

Check the code, please.

Thanks

Comment: Try with $(document).on("submit", "#cover_letter_edit_sec", function (e) {

Comment: Thanks @Mat This is working, What was the issue in previous code can you explain please ?

Comment: Hi, I only changed wording in text, not the code :) seems to get fixed itself